# Java two way role management

Tags: java

I am designing some Java application that has users and teams:

```
public abstract class AbstractUser()

public class BasicUser extends AbstractUser()

public class AnotherUser extends AbstractUser()
```

Now I have teams that contain users:

```
public abstract class AbstractTeam() {
  protected List<AbstractUser> members;
}

public class PublicTeam extends AbstractTeam()
```

Now I need to manage the teams and so each user should have a team status, for example Member, Moderator, Administrator, Owner etc.

So I thought of doing some interfaces:

```
public Interface TeamRole

public Interface Member extends TeamRole

public Interface Moderator extends TeamRole
```

and let the AbsractUser class implement TeamRole:

```
public abstract class AbstractUser implements TeamRole
```

Now what I want to do: Lets have a controller that handles deleting an entry that a user made:

```
public boolean deleteEntry(User u, Entry e, requestingUser r) {

}
```

How can I get a clean representation so I can do something like:

```
u.getEntries().removeIf(entry -> entry.equals(e));
```

In a clean way without 'trying' all roles in a if-statement?

Update: This may not sound 'good', but it is just to descrive the problem of checking for the rights when performing operations

Comment: This does not "smell" correct: `class AbstractUser implements TeamRole`. Shouldn't this be solved by composition and not inheritance?

Comment: Thats why I asked, but also if I give each user a variable of type TeamRole, I would still have the problem of 'cecking' for rights at operations

Comment: @ItFreak Can you explain your thought behind `would still have the problem of 'cecking' for rights at operations`? What purpose would rights serve if you want to avoid checking them?

Comment: Do you mean that user would have different methods based on his rights? I'm not sure I follow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, Hovercraft Full Of Eels is correct in saying that `AbstractUser` should compose `TeamRole` rather than inherit from it (since it's a 'has a' relationship and not an 'is a' relationship).

Now to the question at hand. I'm not sure if I completely understand what you are asking, however I assume you are asking how to check whether or not an `AbstractUser` has permission (or the rights) to perform an action without using an `if` or `switch` statement to check. If so, then here is a way (among a few that I can think of). Create an `Enum` of permission levels each with an ordinal which directly correlates with the permission level. Below is a basic example:

```
class enum PermissionLevel {
    MEMBER(0),
    MODERATOR(1)

    private final int level;

    PermissionLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level; 
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
}
```

Now give the `TeamRole` interface a method that returns the permission level associated with that role

```
public Interface TeamRole {
    PermissionLevel getPermissionLevel();

    ...
}
```

Now when checking if a member has permission all you need to do is an integer comparison on the permission level of the `TeamRole` that the `AbstractUser` has.

```
if (user.getTeamRole().getPermissionLevel().getLevel() > PermissionLevel.MEMBER.getLevel()) {
    // User has permission to do this action
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly my concrete question how to wrap the different levels of rights :)

Comment: @ItFreak This design is a bit odd. I'd expect `TeamMember { userId, role }` rather than having user know about team roles. Also, that's a different idea but why not using inheritance to define a hierarchy of roles and use method signature and types to constrain operations? (see next comment for link)

Answer (score 1):

TeamRole becomes the delete strategy (maybe rename this?).  could use more refactoring but i think the general idea would work.  If we had more roles we can add more classes and implement how they would handle a delete.

```
public class Entry{
}

public class User extends AbstractUser{
}

public abstract class AbstractUser {
    TeamRole role;
    List<Entry> entries;

    //self deletes are always ok
    public void deleteEntry(Entry e){
        this.getEntries().removeIf(entry -> entry.equals(e));
    }

    //delete depending on requested user role
    public void deleteEntry(User requestBy, Entry e){
            role.delete(this, e, requestBy);//mod or other poeple with ability to delete.
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
};

public class BasicUser extends AbstractUser {
};

public class AnotherUser extends AbstractUser {
};

public abstract class AbstractTeam {
    protected List<AbstractUser> members;
}

public class PublicTeam extends AbstractTeam {
};

public interface TeamRole{
    public void delete(AbstractUser user, Entry entry, User requester);
}

public class Member implements TeamRole{
    @Override
    public void delete(AbstractUser user, Entry entry, User requester) {
        if(user==requester) {
            user.deleteEntry(entry);
        }
    }
}

public class Moderator implements TeamRole{
    @Override
    public void delete(AbstractUser user, Entry entry, User requester) {
        user.deleteEntry(entry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there's already an answer, but I thought I could share a different idea where we'd use inheritance to express the role hierarchy and the method signature to constrain operations.

Here's the general design idea:

[image: design]

Usage:

```
public class TeamApplicationService {
    public void doSomethingSpecial(final String teamId) {
        final Team team = teamRepository.teamOfId(teamId);
        final TeamModerator moderator = team.findModerator(currentUserId);
        team.doSomethingSpecial(moderator);
    }
}


public class Team {
    final Map<String, TeamMember> teamMembers;

    public Team() {
        teamMembers = new HashMap<String, TeamMember>();
    }

    public void addMember(final TeamMember member) {
        teamMembers.put(member.userId(), member);
    }

    private <T> T findMemberOfRole(final Class<T> clazz, final String userId) {

        if (!teamMembers.containsKey(userId)) throw couldNotFindMember();

        try {   
            return (T)clazz.cast(teamMembers.get(userId));
        } catch (java.lang.ClassCastException e) {
            throw couldNotFindMember();
        }
    }

    private RuntimeException couldNotFindMember() {
        return new RuntimeException("Could not find member");
    }

    public TeamModerator findModerator(final String userId) {
        return this.<TeamModerator>findMemberOfRole(TeamModerator.class, userId);
    }

    public TeamMember findMember(final String userId) {
        return this.<TeamMember>findMemberOfRole(TeamMember.class, userId);
    }


    public void doSomethingSpecial(TeamModerator moderator) {
        //Moderator only
    }

    public void doSomethingGeneral(TeamMember member) {
        //Any member
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm not entirely sure of the requirements, but here's a [more complex example](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/lLHDRzim3BthLn0vEKLhRDVqOys07N8OMdJT3t0Y9XLWIu4ifok6_FU9fYR8rknXFSm7suaU7ydtQDwthhAkQsgngwksXI_QsRVryLYhNUMKqT_GdjGEuQS0VrLIFdPRVzR32eS_t7B5CHlv6_6CLHFE_Tj6Ni88TnP2QECGd3c2sK_bxFcEVJeu6IN_c3qKHjVt5YrqTBk5NMSjQaT_FLfpKX9jIKV5yZhYGpc0uNdBRqzuDAronhwL6bytCWjXc8SJOUcBud82JUWsncIaFe2n0NCMMQCJ8lxtTga8eFmUJ8y4IpyVzXxEvOs2lcApHGiDFpYut2ij-Q3ebLC-rvIs795houplqJWJsM9ZJZZWPtdpSdAf-j_KVmozVhSnQW_CKcwnDlhGFfirYLWiOpt_u0SpiIk9leatHgAjV10qyIrnA1xd9l75q5Izo7F9EYNuCs3TugWD8XuGP57nRTBXjZhXs6BK4cYl2DvbRCJDpVfmi7Ye73uPu-xkk1WbwHu7J8ss51tc5OhpS75H0X66YkDonkYXHTTP3HfVOOZmznVLHgLzZlavZOniDUgsixZkt8knA3-_5GEsSAK1J5Xmhf5cF68Jch5e8zNuYypLWxa92RXb0dnurG4R27DWFfx-kriDXvg1wQP9KFnVTB76lICRwOZYSYVpBbD7vqtba98BA9Q9ovEBVrQpa3OtSePkHjcSBXkaj8Dyd6OAoOOgQX-ICgKu1m1hzxUnuvtsYKUmhtB31wHtCaa5JyjucQvWQqoDbQQqejyDLrUmk5XmzbNW58I6nOUo_BWO07nGx8D2-Ujd-0K3aqQJrfEDwmj5BUS4kVVdNLF_0W00) based off comments.

Comment: I like this approach because it is clear how the roles and privileges by watching the UML hierarchy, this and the good usage of generics  were my only points why I would think of choosing inheritance over composition here

Comment: Just a little question: for your approach I cannot use the superclass for the roles (in this case TeamMember)? A user would implement TeamMember and get a rank and than can I pass this user with its "TeamMember" to this methods? And how about letting a Team know about its users and not only TeamMembers?

Comment: I'd need more clarifications. To me it makes no sense for a user to implement `TeamMember`, as a TeamMember expresses the relationship between a user and a specific team. Could you explain the real business problem you are trying to solve (the important aspects) and then show which solution you are attempting to implement. The reason `Team` should not encapsulate `User` objects is because `Team` and `User` are most likely different aggregate roots, which have their own transactional boundary. Please read [Effective aggregate design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/).

Comment: For an example of this approach you could check the `moderatePost` function [here](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/application/forum/PostApplicationService.java) and [there](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/domain/model/forum/Forum.java).

Comment: Hi, I did not watched your links yet, but I will do. To explain the concrete use cases: There are useres, tems and entries. Users can post entries. Users can join none, one or more than one teams. Entries can belong to a specific team or can be public (which could be easily implemented by using a public default theme). The main problem is in the relation user -> more than one team. How to handle rights for one user in multiple teams? So how to handle UserA being normal user in Team1 and moderator or owner in Team2?

Comment: @ItFreak  `"So how to handle UserA being normal user in Team1 and moderator or owner in Team2"`. This answer handles that, given that `Team` holds memberships. The specific kind of `TeamMember` defines the role that is played within a specific team and which user plays it. Now, to help you model the system I'd need to learn more about a few things. How many members do you expect in each teams in average? Is there any business rules that constrains posting entries (e.g. maximum number of entries by specific user, etc.)? Give as much info as you as these affect the design (trade-offs).

Comment: thank you for your help. I expect about 50 members in a team, the number of teams is not known and not relevant for this scenario. I have not planned any restraints expect the mentioned rules for operations correlating with user ranks. Just a additional information: I plan to have more than one moderator and administrator but only one member. So I think if having Map<AbstractUser, TeamRole> in each team (this would separate a user from its specific role in a specific team) but struggle to bring this to a real scenario, maybe you have a better idea.

Comment: I modified the answer with a more complete design. Pay attention to composition vs aggregation in the diagram. Aggregate roots are never composed of other aggregate roots, they only reference each other by ID. If you have a lot of members per team you may have to model the `TeamMember` as an aggregate root of it's own instead of the collection within `Team` and use a domain service to cast a `User` to a member of a specific team. E.g. `teamMemberService.findModeratorOfTeam(teamId, userId)`. You would also have to use DB unique constraints to ensure the set validation.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, really helped me. So in case of an unauthorized operation I could just throw an exception and pass it back. Really appreciate that. Just one last question : I can't find the difference I  your plantuml between deleting with member and moderator grants

Comment: Oh right, I haven't written that calling code path. Well you have 2 choices here I'd say. Assuming standard members could only remove their own entries from teams I modeled `removeOwnEntry` as a distinct operation to be able to leverage the method signature to express roles, but then this means the calling logic will have to call the right operation (e.g. `if (entry.wasAuthoredBy(userId)) team.removeOwnEntry(…);`). You could also decide to use a single operation `removeEntry(member, entry)`...

Comment: but then you'd have to check if member is an instance of `TeamModerator` when the entry does not belong to the member.